# Convert Mat to Bitmap in windows application

Tags: c++, opencv, winapi, bitmap

I need some image processing in my win32 application and I'm using opencv for this. I read image files by opencv and try converting it to HBITMAP to show it with StretchBlt. I have a function for this:

```
void ConvertMatToBMP(Mat& mat, HBITMAP& hbitmap)
{
// define Bitmap Info structures
BITMAPINFO bmpInfo;
BITMAPINFOHEADER bmpInfoHeader;

// set members of BITMAPINFOHEADER
bmpInfoHeader.biSize = sizeof(bmpInfoHeader);
bmpInfoHeader.biWidth = mat.cols;
bmpInfoHeader.biHeight = -mat.rows;
bmpInfoHeader.biPlanes = 1;

switch (mat.depth())
{
case CV_8U:
case CV_8S:
    bmpInfoHeader.biBitCount = mat.channels() * 8;
    break;
case CV_16U:
case CV_16S:
    bmpInfoHeader.biBitCount = mat.channels() * 16;
    break;
case CV_32S:
case CV_32F:
    bmpInfoHeader.biBitCount = mat.channels() * 32;
    break;
case CV_64F:
    bmpInfoHeader.biBitCount = mat.channels() * 64;
    break;
default:
    bmpInfoHeader.biBitCount = 0;
    break;
}

bmpInfoHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
bmpInfoHeader.biSizeImage = 0;
bmpInfoHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
bmpInfoHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
bmpInfoHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
bmpInfoHeader.biClrImportant = 0;

// set members of BITMAPINFO
bmpInfo.bmiHeader = bmpInfoHeader;
bmpInfo.bmiColors->rgbBlue = 0;
bmpInfo.bmiColors->rgbGreen = 0;
bmpInfo.bmiColors->rgbRed = 0;
bmpInfo.bmiColors->rgbReserved = 0;

HDC hdc = GetDC(imageview.ifHandle);
hbitmap = CreateDIBitmap(hdc, &bmpInfoHeader, CBM_INIT, mat.data, &bmpInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
ReleaseDC(imageview.ifHandle, hdc);
}
```

but it is not working 100% correctly. for some images the hbitmap is null, for some others the image is crooked and noisy or grayscale. I ignored the problem first but now I have the same problem when processing valid images.
for example after resizing mat to a small size and convert it to bitmap, same problem is happening for hbitmap. weird part is when I cropp image the first one row of pixels and most of the time the problem is gone.
My question is what is the problem with my code? or is there a better way of doing these kind of things?

Comment: Please see the supported values for the *biBitCount* field of the [BITMAPINFOHEADER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183376.aspx) structure. Also note, that any bit depth lower than 16 implies usage of a color palette. Plus, scanlines in a bitmap need to be `DWORD`-aligned. It's not clear whether `Mat` implements this constraint.

Comment: all of my images are 24bit. I didn't understand "scanlines in a bitmap need to be DWORD-aligned"?

Comment: 24bpp images need special attention. See [Bitmap Header Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183386.aspx): *"The scan lines are DWORD aligned [...]. They must be padded for scan line widths, in bytes, that are not evenly divisible by four [...]. For example, a 10- by 10-pixel 24-bpp bitmap will have two padding bytes at the end of each scan line."*

Comment: So how should I give it mat data?

Comment: Unless `Mat`'s data is properly aligned, you cannot pass it to `CreateDIBitmap`. Your options are: `1` Copy `Mat`'s data into a temporary buffer, applying appropriate padding. `2` Make `Mat`'s width a multiple of 4. `3` Make `Mat` a 32bpp image.

Comment: thanks. solution 1 worked although it is a little slow. at first run it gave null for all images including former valid results, but after setting biBitCount=32 it is working 100% correctly.

Comment: That doesn't sound correct. If setting *biBitCount* to 32 fixes your issues, then your source images are 32bpp (not 24bpp as you previously claimed). A 32bpp image's scanlines are always `DWORD` aligned, because every pixel is encoded using 4 bytes, so you could pass the `Mat` data as is.

Comment: I'm sure they are 24bit.I checked them using photoshop and also opencv. these are my results: 1) I copy mat's data to a buffer in a 24bit order and set biBitCount to 24: As I said 90% of images are valid, but when I reduce their size or make any other change that 10% grows to 80% . 2) when I copy data in 32bit order and set biBitCount to 24 all of HBITMAPs are null. 3) when I copy data in 32bit order and set biBitCount to 32 all of the results are valid even when I process images. That's weird!

Comment: *"I'm sure they are 24bit.I checked them using photoshop"* - Photoshop cannot read image data from your process. You must have exported it. In other words: You changed it. If setting *biBitCount* to 32 solves the issue for you it stands to reason that your data **is** 32 bpp.

Comment: They are jpg files with 3 channels. how can they be 32bpp. Also using windows explorer->properties->detail tab->bit depth gives 24.

Comment: You are looking at **files**, but are asking about in-memory representation in a `cv::Mat` object. Looking at files has no bearing on the in-memory representation. If you are using Visual Studio 2012/13/15, check out the [Image Watch](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WolfKienzle.ImageWatch) extension to gather information from the in-memory representation of a `cv::Mat` object. See the [introduction](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_image_watch/windows_visual_studio_image_watch.html) for more information.

Comment: My version is 2017. I tried installing the extension but failed. you mean all of jpg files are 32bpp? because every file I opened with my former code, has those issues.

Comment: What I'm trying to get across is simply this: Once the call `imread` returns, the returned object is no longer a .jpg file. It's a buffer with raw data, and it can have been transformed in a bazillion ways. You need to look at the `Mat` object when you want to find out, what data it holds. Looking at the source files is meaningless. Have you stepped through your code in a debugger to find out, what you need to know?

Comment: the only thing I have done is that I moved the pointer to mat.data byte by byte and realized that each 3 byte is corresponding to one pixel.